# Render custom controls in mvc in C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a need to display many different data types on an MVC page using C#.

What is the best way to code this up. I have 200 items with 10-15 different data types I want to be able to edit.

I could put all of the code in the cshtml but would prefer to, as I have with the original php code, call a function to render the controls.

```
if(controlType = "checkBox"
{
   ...
}
else if(controlType = "string"
{
   ...
}
else if(controlType = "myClassType"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use Html.EditorFor, it shows controls depending upon dataType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Html.EditorFor`. It will look for a matching template depending on the datatype of the property in the ViewModel in the `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` folder.

For example, you can define a template `Boolean.cshtml` to render a checkbox for boolean values of your model.

See [Using Display Templates and Editor Templates in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm).

Answer (score 0):

**The EditorFor() helper displays a user interface for editing a model property. This user interface is known as Editor Template.** 
Check the below example for more details,I have  Index() action,,return a list of object with different datatypes

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    NorthwindEntities db=new NorthwindEntities();
    Employee emp = db.Employees.Find(1);
    return View(emp);
}
```

The preceding code retrieves an Employee from the database whose EmployeeID is 1. It then passes this Employee object to the Index view. The Index view contains the following markup:

```
@model Demo.Models.Employee

@{
    Layout = null;
}
...
<body>
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.EmployeeID)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.FirstName)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.BirthDate)
    }
</body>
</html>
```

It then uses the DisplayFor() helper to show three model properties
 EmployeeID, FirstName, and BirthDate.